# How do tbuffers operate in DirectX?

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11

I've read through the documentation on MSDN but there is very little relating to exactly what a tbuffer is, how it works, its use in graphics programming, and how exactly to create it. I was wondering if anyone here would have a clearer explanation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have DirectX SDK installed, you can take a look at the DirectX10 **Skinning10 Sample** which uses the texture buffers.

The following page also have some code snippet at the bottom to create the texture buffers in DirectX11.

[Shader Constants (HLSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-constants)